# Hide parameter value from URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a URL like this

> `http://localhost/PW/LeaveWithoutPay/Edit?id=9`

and I want to hide the `id?=9` from my URL. Can any one demonstrate how to hide this `id` parameter with an example? I am using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: use http post to call url

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you want to hide it? The client will need to know the ID one way or another. Is it just to "prettify" the URL?

Answer (score 1):

You must need to implement Post method instead of GET method. Here is a sample example for it.

In your controller define something like this

```
    public ActionResult Edit([FromBody] int id) {
        TempData["MsgText"] = id.ToString();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Now in your view, implement the POST method. A sample example is:

`@{string id =(string)TempData["MsgText"];}`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmCallThis" })){

@Html.Label("label",string.IsNullOrEmpty(id)?"No Id Provided":"Current ID = " + id)

@Html.TextBox("id");

<input type="submit" value="Get This Printed" />

}
```

Finally you have the following output: (Before Submit)
[image]

And After submit:

[image]

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

Only one thing you have to doing here is using POST, not GET method. Because the web request is usually stateless, so I don't think we have any other methods to hide your id.